# Bump root package.json version with lerna

Tags: lerna

When I call `lerna version 1.0.0` it bumps the versions to 1.0.0 for every package that has changed in the `/packages` dir.

Additionally, I'd like to bump the version of the root `package.json`.
I'm basically trying to do the following in a single commit:

`lerna version --no-git-tag-version --yes 1.0.0 && npm version 1.0.0`

Any tips?

Comment: I've also the same issue, all `package.json`s of the project are bumped except the one in the root? any news about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, It bumps the version of the root `package.json` including  `package.json` resides in `/packages` dir.

`npm version 1.0.0 --no-git-tag-version && npx lerna version 1.0.0 --no-push --no-git-tag-version --yes`

if lerna is installed

`npm version 1.0.0 --no-git-tag-version && lerna version 1.0.0 --no-push --no-git-tag-version --yes`